# couldn't get data from editText android studio

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-edittext

i created a login form and want to check user credentials is correct or wrong.
but before i found, i could not get editText value in string variables.
so please help me to store editText value.

my java code

```
private String output;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Button button;
public EditText Username,Password;
public String myURL,userValue23,passValue;

List<DataModel> loginList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    userValue23 = Username.getText().toString();
    passValue = Password.getText().toString();

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_login)
    {
        if(inOnline())
        {
            if(userValue=="")
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, userValue+"tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In XML code i created Login Form with two editText Form, and these ID's are respectively etUsername, etPassword, btn_login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     if(inOnline())
            {
                if(userValue=="")
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
```

**You Use value That Name is userValue but you didn't define it, but you Define it you define userValue23 .. fix it and dont need move your varibale to onclick function 
   **

```
                    Toast.makeText(this, userValue+"tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these

```
userValue23 = Username.getText().toString();
passValue = Password.getText().toString();
```

inside onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v) {

if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_login)
{
    userValue23 = Username.getText().toString();
    passValue = Password.getText().toString();
    if(inOnline())
    {
        if(userValue23=="")
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, userValue23+"tees", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move these two lines

```
userValue23 = Username.getText().toString();
passValue = Password.getText().toString();
```

inside the `OnClick` method. Otherwise they will always be empty `OnCreate`.